# ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Yesterday updated my ubuntu 17.04 to ubuntu 17.10. any comments? Appear when I try to run server in pycharm. #django project.

```
bash -cl "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/bin/python /usr/share/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py check /home/encuentrum/GitLab/encuentrum3/ENCUENTRUM/packers_"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pycharm_run_utils import adjust_django_sys_path
  File "/usr/share/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_run_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 19, in <module>
    from importlib._bootstrap import _ERR_MSG, _exec, _load, _builtin_from_name
  File "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/home/encuentrum/venv-encuentrum3/lib/python3.6/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
```

Comment: Try re-creating the virtual environment for the project.

Comment: thanks Alasdair, but the problem was resolved when upgraded psycopg2 to the recent version to 2.7.3.2

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have mixed your multiple Python installations, the newer version of `weakref` are not compatible with older version python binary, try to remove any one (the older one is recommended) of Python installation.

### Analysis

For my case, I have installed older version Python （3.5.1) before, and upgrade my Debian installation. The newer Debian upgrade it's Python3.5 to 3.5.3 which have `_remove_dead_weakref` in `_weakref` in its Python binary

When I type `$ where python3.5`, I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5    
/usr/local/bin/python3.5    
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

The `/usr/local/bin/python3.5` is my own older installation, and `/usr/bin/python3.5` is Debian offical Python3.5

When I update my Python3.5 installation by apt-get, apt-get execute `python3.5 -E -S /usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py $files` (post-install script) in the deb package.`, it triggers the weakref issue, here is my log

```
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
```

I tested Python 3.5.1 and Python 3.5.3 with same import action, here are the compares

Official Python 3.5.3 from apt-get

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
>>> from _weakref import _remove_dead_weakref
>>>
```

My own Python 3.5.1 installation

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr 23 2016, 16:40:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from _weakref import _remove_dead_weakref
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
>>>
```

So, I confirm that python3.5 in `/usr/local/bin/` cannot use `_remove_dead_weakref`.
But which python did apt-get use in post-installation script? Try it.

```
$ which python3.5
/usr/local/bin/python3.5
```

So, here is why. The post-installation script use my custom installation of python, along with newer python library (`/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py`)

### Fix it!

As I said, disable older version of python

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python3.5.bak
```

Test

```
$ which python3.5
/usr/bin/python3.5
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. disabling older version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Comzyh answer, this indeed is due to mixed python versions when an upgrade happen due to any reason. A quick fix is to remove your venv python binary i.e. `rm <path-to-your-env>/bin/python` and copying your system python binary to your venv like `cp /usr/bin/python <path-to-your-env>/bin/python`. This will fix the weak ref error