# Python error in Vim when run inside a 3.5.3 virtualenv

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I have multiple Python versions installed with `pyenv` on Ubuntu 16.04. I create virtual environments to work with projects using different versions with `pipenv`. However, for Python 3.5.x **only** I get errors like this when I try to edit a file with Vim 8 (installed via the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim)) in an activated virtualenv:

```
"test.py" 49L, 1434C
Error detected while processing function jedi#init_python[4]..<SNR>48_init_python[27]..jedi#setup_python_imports:
line   25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-AYf6DmHL/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 19, in <module>
    from importlib._bootstrap import _ERR_MSG, _exec, _load, _builtin_from_name
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-AYf6DmHL/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-AYf6DmHL/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-AYf6DmHL/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-AYf6DmHL/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
```

The issue seems to affect all python related Vim plugins. With other Python versions (e.g. 3.6.x, 3.7.x) this does not occur. What may be causing this issue?

**Update**: It seems that when I run Vim inside a 3.5.x virtualenv, the Vim's interpreter's `sys.path` gets updated somehow. For example, this is the output of `:py3 import sys; print(sys.path)` inside a 3.6.0 virtualenv:

`['/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5
/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '_vim_path_']`

And this is for 3.5.3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 19, in <module>
    from importlib._bootstrap import _ERR_MSG, _exec, _load, _builtin_from_name
  File "/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
['/must>not&exist', '/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python35.zip', '/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/li
b/python3.5', '/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.
5-8feRiT5s/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/testuser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.7/lib/python3.5', '/home/testuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-3.5-8feRiT5s/lib/pyt
hon3.5/site-packages']
```

The issue can be reproduced in a `ubuntu:16.04` docker container.

Comment: Waht version of Python 3.5? The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949120/7976758 suggests that you need later version (3.5.3+) and you have to recreate the virtualenv with the new Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+%27_remove_dead_weakref%27

Comment: I use virtualenvs with Python 3.5.3 and 3.5.7, they have the same issue. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with system python3 v3.5.2, perhaps it interferes with the virtualenv somehow. I haven't installed any additional pythons to the system itself.

Comment: Which python version was active when you installed all the `vim` plugins?

Comment: @Tarun: I guess, 3.5.3. Actually, it doesn't seem to matter. If I activate a 3.5.3 virtualenv and start Vim w/o any plugins with `vim -u NONE` and then execute the command `:py3 import sys; print(sys.version)` I get exactly the same error. Although, the version 3.5.2 is successfully printed. In a 3.6.x (or even 3.4.x) virtualenv no error occurs.

Comment: This usually happens when the python installation gets corrupted in someway, see these threads https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/issues/1739, https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/2883

Comment: @Tarun: I only have the default 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 pythons on the system. Anyway, how do I check if my python installation is not "corrupted"?

Comment: Probably remove python and reinstall it and reinstall all packages?

Comment: @Tarun: This is definitely not a problem with python installation as the issue can be reproduced in a docker container (`ubuntu:16.04`).

Comment: Can you add the steps to reproduce for docker?

Comment: It seems when you call python 3 virtualenv, the python 3.5.3 installed globally on your machine gets called. For example, I can see /usr/lib/python3.5 in your call to python 3.6 virtual env.  My guess is if you try the above code by calling python in 3.6 virtualenv explicitly, you would probably get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[Debian Bug report logs - #852163: python3.5-minimal wont configure](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852163) demonstrates that this error (for Python 3.5 and Python 3.6) is due to another incompatible installation of Python in /usr/local.

> Some further digging with another user in #debian who was experiencing this 
>   problem indicated that it was related to a locally installed 
>   /usr/local/bin/python3.5. The stdlib in /usr/lib/python3.5 is picked up by the 
>   /usr/local/bin/python3.5 but is not compatible with it, resulting in the 
>   stacktrace shown.
>
> Removing /usr/local/bin/python3* and all traces of that installation from 
>   /usr/local/lib (plus other associated tools) solved this problem for the user 
>   I was helping in #debian.

-- Stuart Prescott ([link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852163#36))

The problem is caused by the system installed python, which conflicts with personally installed python.

Comment: I don't have any versions of Python on the system besides stock 2.7.12 and 3.5.2. As I mentioned, the issue with Vim can be reproduced in a clean docker container. Just install the latest Vim from the linked PPA, `pyenv` (to create a Python 3.5.3 virtual environment), and optionally `pipenv`. Then running `vim -c 'py3 import sys'` inside a 3.5.3 virtual environment will give you the above error.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the case that other python versions are interfering here. Do you have a `PYTHONPATH` set?

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

If it is set you could try to unset it. It's usually not needed when using virtual environments.

Comment: The question is about virtual environment so `$PYTHONPATH` is set and there is no way to unset it.

Comment: I know it's about virtual envs but `$PYTHONPATH` is not necessarily set when using virtuals envs. I mean litteraly `$PYTHONPATH` and not `$PATH`. My thought was that they clash somehow with different python versions.

Comment: `sys.path` is set, that what I meant saying "there is no way to unset it".

Comment: I've checked it and `$PYTHONPATH` is unset.

Answer (score -1):

Try running python with sudo. I think the  python  which comes with OS needs to run with admin privilege.